# Record video of HTML5 WebGL on backend

Tags: html, node.js, webgl, backend

Is it possible to record video (including sound) of an HTML5 WebGL video playing, for browsers that do not support HTML5 WebGL?  For example, would it be possible to record SeriouslyJS (http://seriouslyjs.org/) stuff on the backend, in a format that would be well received by majority of browsers / devices?

I've done a lot of backend stuff but never anything involving a backend GUI...  I appreciate any help anyone can give me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use screen capture software (such as [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/)) to record one or more static videos, and then present it as a video to non-enabled browsers. On the JavaScript side, you'd need to "fall back" to the video. Pseudo-code ensues:

```
var canvas = document.getElementByID('webgl-canvas');
var webgl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
if (!webgl) {
  /*
    create a <video> element and replace the <canvas>
    tag with it. Or, have the <video> tag already
    created and hidden with CSS, and display it at this
    time.
  */
} else {
  /*
    Proceed with the interactive, WebGL-enabled version.
  */
}
```

However, the video will obviously be limited by technology: it's a pre-recoded, non-interactive video. To achieve a pseudo-interactive style (as long as it's as simple as button presses, per your link), you could use the [HTML5 media API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/media-elements.html#htmlmediaelement) to dynamically switch between multiple pre-recorded videos, but I don't know how well this would work in practice because of bandwidth and synchronization issues. You would probably want to validate that there is an acceptable amount of buffering on each video prior to starting the sequence.

Note: the above proposal assumes at least HTML5 support, even in lieu of WebGL. If you're targeting older browsers with no HTML5 support, I think you may be stuck with something as simple as a YouTube video.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question might be [in this blog post](http://www.oampo.co.uk/2011/01/exporting-video-from-webgl/). The author uses the canvas.toDataURL() method to send each frame to a simple node.js instance he created. The node.js instance saves each frame as a PNG file. After all frames are saved, the author seems to use something like [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) to generate a video from the images. You could then serve this video as an alternative to the actual animation. This is quite a workaround but seemed to work well for the author.